# Excel VBA - Oracle DB Connection - Execution of Update Query not working

Tags: excel, oracle, vba

I'm using Excel VBA to connect with an Oracle DB and run some queries. I've ran some complex select queries and it works fine. But it unable to run a simple Update query. When I run the query, the application hangs and the query isn't executed (I have checked the DB and don't see any updates to it). The update query runs fine when I execute it using SQL developer. Please help. Following is the code -

```
Sub checkupd()

strDriver = "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle"
strHost = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Querygen").Cells(3, 17).Value
strPort = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Querygen").Cells(4, 17).Value
strUser = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Querygen").Cells(5, 17).Value
strPassword = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Querygen").Cells(6, 17).Value
strSID = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Querygen").Cells(7, 17).Value

'Connection String
strCon = strCon & "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION="
strCon = strCon & "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)"
strCon = strCon & "(HOST=" & strHost & ")(PORT=" & strPort & "))"
strCon = strCon & "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=" & strSID & "))); "
strCon = strCon & "uid=" & strUser & ";pwd=" & strPassword & ";"

strQueryup = "UPDATE DM_RESERVE SET COL1 = 'new3'"
strQueryup = strQueryup & " WHERE PROD IN ('123','456')"


Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open strCon

conn.Execute strQueryup 


MsgBox ("Update Query executed")


conn.Close


Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, I'm using excel 2013. I have tried debugging with breakpoints. There's some issue with the execute statement. The code works smooth before that statement, excel hangs when the code reaches the "conn.execute" statement. One might think that its taking time to execute the query. I left it hanged for 10 mins but there was still not a single update in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help.
I was able to resolve this by using a "COMMIT" before and after the Update query.

```
...
conn.Execute "COMMIT"
conn.Execute strQueryup 
conn.Execute "COMMIT"
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any syntax issue, I can see a space issue. Can you try this

```
strQueryup = "UPDATE DM_RESERVE SET COL1 = 'new3'"
strQueryup = strQueryup & " WHERE PROD IN ('123','456')"
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Didnt get any syntax issue. I tried running what you have provided. But getting the same issue (Excel hangs). I even tried by putting the proper query in one single line. But same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Driver "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle) for ages. Install [ODBC driver from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-098976.html) and try it again.